# Prolog zipping with mergesort

Tags: prolog

I tried using this code but it not given output for all inputs.

```
zip([], [], []).
zip([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :- zip(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Actually I have to do this task
Define a Prolog relation on three arguments, zip/3, where the third argument is the list that is a zipping of the first and second, and use it to implement mergesort. The relation should allow queries of the following form:
I want a program in which inputs and output are...

> ?- zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]). yes
>
> ?- zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]). no
>
> ?- zip([1,2], [3,4], X). X = [1,2,3,4]
>
> ?- zip([1,2], [2,3], X).
>
> X = [1,2,3]
>
> ?- zip([1,3], [2,4], X). X = [1,2,3,4]
>
> ?- zip([1,4], [2,3], X). X = [1,2,3,4]
>
> ?- zip(X, [1,2], [1,2,3]).  # lists that zip with [1,2] to give
>   [1,2,3]
>
> X = [1,2,3] ? ;
>
> X = [1,3] ? ;
>
> X = [2,3] ? ;
>
> X = [3] ? ; no

Comment: Hint: you never checked if `X < Y`, `X > Y`, `X == Y`, etc. to determine what element to "yield" first.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your sample code:

- You aren't comparing `X` and `Y` to order things properly, and
- You're making the assumption that the two lists are of equal length.

Try something like this:

```
merge( []     , []     , []     ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Xs] ) .
merge( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Ys] ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- X @<  Y , merge(    Xs  , [Y|Ys] , Zs ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- X =@= Y , merge(    Xs  , [Y|Ys] , Zs ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- X @>  Y , merge( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  , Zs ) .
```